# Logical expression in Mysql statement not giving desired result

Tags: mysql, logical-operators, short-circuiting

Okey, first of all, let me draw the related table and dummy data that being used before going further(*simple table structure to re-produce the issue*):

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|users                                         |
|----------------------------------------------|
|ID | name            | email                  | 
|----------------------------------------------| 
|1  | jack jill       | jackjill@gmail.com     |
|----------------------------------------------|                  
|2  | jack jacky      | jackjacky@gmail.com    |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

And here is mysql query statement being used :

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `ID` = 1
AND  `name` LIKE '%jacky%'
OR  `email` LIKE '%jacky%'
```

**Expected result : Row no 1**

**Actual result : Row no 2**

**Question :**

1) Is the logical expression in above statement do the short circuit evaluation?

2) If yes( from question no 1 ), why it not return the 1st row as the first expression already evaluated to TRUE.

3) If not( from question no 1 ), which expression its evaluated and at what order the operator precedence occurred?

All these are playing in my mind right now, and i'm really confuses on how it evaluated. Even it just a simple SQL statement. Really appreciated if someone can explain deep down about this.

Comment: There is an error in your data. You want the `y` after `jack`.

Comment: @trincot no, that's my real live data looks like

Comment: In that case you cannot expect a match with the first row, even if you would correct the precedence issue. Your conditions require the presence of `jacky` with `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, the `AND` operator has precedence over `OR`. So you probably want to override that with parentheses like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `ID` = 1
AND  (   `name` LIKE '%jacky%'
     OR  `email` LIKE '%jacky%'
     )
```

In your version the last condition (i.e. `email LIKE '%jacky%'`) was enough to get a match. You could imagine the default precedence like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE (     `ID` = 1
       AND  `name` LIKE '%jacky%'
      )
OR    `email` LIKE '%jacky%'
```

With the corrected version there will in fact be no more match, as there is no `jacky` in the *name* field of the first row, nor in its *email* field.

Comment: Ok, when look at 2nd query of your example, make me clear how it goes

Comment: What i actually think is, why it not returning the first rows as the ID already equal to 1, and if it doing short circuit, why not returning the first rows and left behind the rest operand. Like this `(ID = 1) AND (name LIKE '%jacky%') AND (email LIKE '%jacky%')`

Comment: But if that is what you want, you should not say "AND". If having the correct ID is enough for you to have a match, then you don't want to add another condition with "AND". Change it to "OR" for short-circuit. Then the door is still open to other rows that might satisfy those other conditions and not have ID 1.

Comment: Make senses. So all it does is comparing both `(ID = 1 AND  name LIKE %jacky%')` which return FALSE, and next comparing `(FALSE) OR (email LIKE '%jacky%')`, end up the final expression look likes is `(FALSE) OR (TRUE)` and returned TRUE result which is the email with jacky wording, am i right?

Comment: Alright, much thanks.. really clear now. One more thing, this is just a quick and simple question. Let say i have 10 rows data inside the table, 5 of them having name `john` and the another 5 data having name `phil`,  and If i have sql `select *from name like %john% or name like %phil%`, is it the sql driver will searching `(name like %john%)` for all data(10) first, and again searching `(name like %phil%)` for all data(10) separately? I mean row by row for each expression.

Comment: No, the engine will pass through the records only once and check for each the first condition. If the first condition is true, that record is taken without checking the second condition. If not true, the second condition is checked immediately, in the same pass.

Comment: Alright,, really appreciated the answers. Thanks trincot. Time to pay for that(answer accepted)  :)